# Pause code if CPU gets too hot

Tags: python, performance, cpu, cpu-usage

I'm running a quite CPU intensive `python` code in my desktop PC and I was wondering if there was an easy way to check for CPU temperature and pause it for a couple of minutes if it gets above a certain max limit.

Comment: This is not a precaution I would consider in my program. Even if you could do this easily how do you know that is your program that is causing the heating or that pausing the program would cause the CPU to cool down?  It could be possible the CPU is hot for another reason and you'd be pausing your program to no effect thus rendering it useless

Comment: Well that's a pretty extreme case in which I have no clue what my PC is doing. In my case I plan on letting the code running almost by itself (plus the core system of course) so this is not really a concern. My concern is that my CPU could overheat and hang my system.

Comment: I'd say leave it to your hardware to decide when to slow the CPU.  Most PC class machines monitor the CPU temperature themselves and will slow themselves down to avoid damage.  If this is an embedded system without such checks, it's probably not safe to put the monitoring code in the application-- you probably want it at the firmware level.